# Usage of Initialization On Demand Holder idiom is giving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, singleton, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement  Initialization On Demand Holder idiom in my code for Database connection manager for Lazy loading

```
Class ConfigurationAgent{
private ConfigurationAgent(){
    String baseDir = "XYZ";
}
private static class LazyLoader{
    private static final ConfigurationAgent instance = new ConfigurationAgent();
}
public static ConfigurationAgent getInstance(){
    ConfigurationAgent cfg = LazyLoader.instance;
    return cfg;
}
}
```

Now I am calling this ConfigurationAgent's instance from another class using below :

```
ConfigurationAgent agent = ConfigurationAgent.getInstance();
```

In this case I am getting ExceptionInInitializerError followed by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors.

My guess is static class LazyLoader is not getting loaded properly because of which the call "LazyLoader.instance" is giving this issue. (This issue is mentioned in following wiki link without any solution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom)
Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Comment: I don't know what's your problem? you get NoClassDefFoundError because `new ConfigurationAgent();` throws an exception. you just need fix that!

Comment: can you plz let me know how to do that ?

Comment: that depends how you implements the constructor ConfigurationAgent(). would you pls post the full stacktrace of your exception? maybe you missed the most critical one.

Comment: @turtledove Thanks a ton, because of your inputs i was able to figure out that in my private constructor ConfigurationAgent() i making some some call to System properties which were not properly set, hence giving NullPointerException. Because of this the object of class ConfigurationAgent was not created properly, hence the NoClassDefFoundError error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already written in the comments to the question: Most likely there is an **Exception thrown in the constructor**, which then shows up as the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Check the stack trace.

*(I run into the same, and SO helped to take a closer look and the constructor, and I like questions with accepted answers, so here's my roundup.)*

Comment: yes.. I figured that out 2 years back after posting the question. Thought of answering my own question but too lazy for that. Thanks anyway for the answer.